# ワードプレス化、パスの置き換えについて

Tags: wordpress

wordpressを用いてWebサイトを作成しているのですが（オリジナルテーマ作成）
以下のエラーメッセージが表示され、ページが表示されません。

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_template_directory_uri() ~~
```

エラーメッセージの出る箇所は、

`<link rel="icon" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/~~` ここで出ています。
wordpress関数だからでしょうか？

Local by Flywheelでhtmlからphpに変換してます。

またindex.phpからnews.phpへリンクをクリックしても先ほどのエラーが出て飛びません。

`<li><a href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/news.php">NEWS</a></li>`

index.phpのスタイルシートは読み込めてます。

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style.css">`

Comment: wordpressで設定した　パーマリンクで呼び出して表示していますか？直接パスを指定したテーマファイルの呼び出しはwordpressで定義されている関数は呼び出せません。

Comment: その通りでした！パーマリンクで無事解決できました。